# Get $.post to Return a View

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a view in `ASP.NET` `MVC 5`, on which a user types in some data and I am going to send that data to my `controller` in `C#`, and then send the user to the next `view`. The current code I have is as follows:

---

Javascript:

```
function goToNextQuestion(output) {
    $.post("submitUserAnswer", { userOutput: output }, doStuff(), String);
}

function doStuff() {
    alert("doing");
}
```

C#:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult submitUserAnswer(String userOutput)
    {
        //store userOutput
        return View("Index");
    }
```

My alert is popping up, so I assume the `$.post` is working.....but the view isn't changing to "Index" (yes, "Index" is a valid view). And `submitUserAnswer` is a valid path I believe, I am not getting a `404 error`. Does anyone know 1) what is going wrong and 2) how can I fix what I have or do something differently to get my view to display?

Comment: Your not doing anything with the view you return from the method - i.e. updating the DOM with it (and in any case it needs to be a partial view). But it sounds like you really want to redirect to a new view (`Index.cshtml`) in which case, dont use ajax - do a normal submit and redirect in the POST method (ajax stays on the same page - it does not redirect)

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do, i'll have to do some research on submit/redirect

Comment: Just as a side note - if you did want to stay on the same page and update the DOM with a partial view it would be `$.post(yourUrl, { userOutput: output }, function(data) { $(someElement).html(data); }` or `$(someElement).append(data);`

Comment: That is good to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY DOING THIS

```
function goToNextQuestion(output) {
doStuff();
var url = '@Url.Content("~/ControllerName/submitUserAnswer?userOutput=")' + output;
window.location.href = url;
}

function doStuff() {
alert("doing");
}
```

And you dont need **[HttpPost]** in the controller

```
public ActionResult submitUserAnswer(String userOutput)
{
    //store userOutput
    return View("Index");
}
```

Comment: theres an edit, take a look! it'll work the way you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Use`RedirectToAction()` method instead of the `View()` method.